# Travis with firebase hosting and create-react-app: can't find public directory

Tags: travis-ci, create-react-app

I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/blob/master/user/deployment/firebase.md) yet my travis build is failing because of:

> Specified public directory does not exist, can't deploy hosting

The **yarn build** succeeds but deployment fails. Could it be that the firebase gem of Travis is ignoring the hosting/public key in the  firebase.json?

My .travis.yml

```
  language: node_js
  warnings_are_errors: false
  node_js:
  - '9'
  before_script:
  - export CI=false
  cache:
    yarn: true
    directories:
      - node_modules
  before_deploy:
    - yarn build
  deploy:
    provider: firebase
    token:
      secure: xxx
  env:
    global:
    - secure: xxx
```

My firebase.json

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add

```
deploy:
   skip_cleanup: true
```

to your .travis.yml . The git stash --all step will remove your local build directory before the deploy phase. Hence it can't find your build dir.